# Simply function with similar properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, tween

**How do I simplify the following function?**

I have a bunch of tweens that have basicailly the same ease properties.
I realize this question is pretty broad, but I've haven't come up with anything satisfactory enough.

```
    $('input').change(function() {
    if($("#radio").is(":checked")){

        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(tween1.scale).to({ y: 4 }, 1000).start();
        tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
        tween.yoyo(true);

        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(tween2.position).to({ y: 0.05 }, 1000).start();
        tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
        tween.yoyo(true);

        var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(tween3.scale).to({ y: 6 }, 1000).start();
        tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
        tween.yoyo(true);

        ...

 }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most classic way is to declare a function:

```
function doTween(attr, y) {
    var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(attr).to({ y: y }, 1000).start();
    tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut);
    tween.yoyo(true);
}
```

and call using

```
doTween( tween1.scale, 4 );
doTween( tween2.position, 0.05 );
doTween( tween3.scale, 6 );
```